# cannot Resolve Method setLatestEventInfo in android notification

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I just imported an android project and in the Notification section, I have to use setLatestEventInfo. But Android Studio Says cannot resolve method setLatestEventinfo. Here is my code snippet, please kindly help edit my code while answering

```
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"CEPF Mobile",0);
            Intent notify_intent = new Intent(context,SpecialSerivceReportActivity.class);
            notify_intent.putExtra("filename", "Special Service Report");
            notify_intent.putExtra("URL", urls[0]);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,(int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notify_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "CEPF Mobile", "New post in Special Service Report", contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND ;
            nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
            }
            else if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("Special Columnist Blog"))
            {

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"CEPF Mobile",0);
            Intent notify_intent = new Intent(context,SpecialSerivceReportActivity.class);
            notify_intent.putExtra("filename", "Special Columnist Blog");
            notify_intent.putExtra("URL", urls[1]);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,(int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notify_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "CEPF Mobile", "New post in Special Columnist Blog", contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND ;
            nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
            }
```

Comment: Same here, albeit on Eclipse, in code I haven't touched in a while, with a few updates to Eclipse, ADT and Android SDK since then. The API docs don't mention the method – though that code used to run. Thus, it's unlikely the culprit is Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

`setLatestEventInfo()` has been [removed](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html) from `Notification` in API 23. You'll need to rewrite your code if you target API 23 or higher.

Instead of:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"CEPF Mobile",0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "CEPF Mobile", "New post in Special Columnist Blog", contentIntent);
```

Do:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("CEPF Mobile")
.setContentText("New post in Special Columnist Blog")
.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
Notification notification = builder.buid();
```

A few notes on usage:

- If you use the Android Support Library, use `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead of `Notification.Builder`.
- Since you're setting a couple more attributes on your notifications, look at the methods offered by the builder class, and consider using these, especially if you create similar notifications in different places.
- Using the app's main icon for a notification is not recommended, as Android now forces notification icons to be rendered in black and white, with all opaque areas rendered as white. You'll probably want to design an icon that is still recognizable in this setting.

Answer (score 0):

For the Best Approach, Create Notification codes from the support of android studio,

Right click on **app** and click **New** then **UI Components** then **Notification** then click finish.

The code is ready to be used.

Comment: did find the UI Components after clicking new